# Use LAN with Cloud

Tags: cloud

I have a scenario in my new office that I have only client PC's which i have to setup a server to manage these PC's. So of the high cost of server, can i use any of the cloud computing services to do so, so that all my PC's will b managed by the cloud service(i think it is active directory). Please help me in how can i do this?

I thought of having an internal server that will manage the client PC's. But the cost of server is a big problem. Also we will need to expand the server config when requirement increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a brief look, Microsoft offers Azure Active Directory(http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/), which has a free trial. If the server is cost prohibitive, I would consider looking into the *long term* cost of the cloud service to see if it really outweighs the purchase of on-campus equipment. The problem with cloud services is that you are now dependent on your internet connection for people to log into their systems and interact with the directory. What happens if the connection goes down?

Another option, depending on the size of the business and it's needs, are to purchase a couple of lower end server options and host active directory and other services in appropriate VMs. This will be a bigger up front cost but MAY be a more robust solution depending on your needs.

Furthermore, security is always a consideration when using cloud services - make sure you read up on the docs and have a good idea of how to keep thing secure (you'll be passing user credentials back and forth to AD).

Comment: I need up to 20 clients only. And in this need to connect laptops to this AD from remote locations. So what option will be good for me as should be cost effective on long term (since there may chance of increasing the number of clients, and thereby upgrade server config which may tends to make the current server config unusable).

Comment: As Jeff Muzzy mentions, you can get server equipment cheaply. And a little bit of hardware goes a long way with user numbers as low as you are talking about. If you choose a cloud service, you are paying for convenience. The question you need to ask yourself is if you want to save money or if you want a convenient externally managed service. What is best for the business? if the latter, explore the cloud route.  Another option to consider is if the Microsoft stack is even right for the business. There are other options depending on the environment and technical levels of the employees.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure this belongs here but I'll try and answer.

Going to the cloud only saves you the capex costs of doing something or getting something going quickly.  You still will have to account for the OpEx costs of having stuff in the cloud.  The monthly, VM cost, networking traffic.  You get free into cloud but every outbound traffic is going cost you something.  Read that all the traffic pushed to your clients in your office will keep th

I have a local recycler (Seattle) here that sells HP DL180 (Dual Quad Core Rack mounted servers for 69$ that use SAS or SATA drives Raid controller and 4GB of ram) for 69$.

I have work on a few startups where OpEx over ran the Cap in less than 7 months.